# google ads didn't work with me

Tags: java, android, admob

helo

i use this

```
<com.google.ads.AdView
        xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        ads:adSize="BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="a1517edc9c6ed63" />
```

and in java

```
 AdView adView = (AdView)this.findViewById(R.id.adView);
            adView.loadAd(new AdRequest());
```

and in AndroidManifest

```
<activity android:name="com.google.ads.AdActivity"
                  android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"/>
    </application>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
</manifest>
```

and i Brought the exetrnal JAR (GoogleAdMobAdsSdk-6.4.1)

but he didn't work with me.

Comment: ***sigh*** Didn't work ***how***?! What error do you get? What do you see that you didn't expect to see? What *didn't* you see that you expected to see? What have you done to debug it?

Answer (score 0):

add this line in your layout xml file on the

xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"

as like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
android:id="@+id/LinearLayout01"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical" >
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/LinearLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    <com.google.ads.AdView
        xmlns:googleads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
        android:id="@+id/ad"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
        app:adSize="BANNER"
        app:adUnitId="@string/admob_id" >
    </com.google.ads.AdView>
</LinearLayout>
 </LinearLayout>
```